# Action Overflow error in Physical Navigation Key Android

Tags: android, key, overflow, action

Guys i create an application that using action bar action overflow ( three dots on the right side ). It runs well in my Android 5.0.1 lollipop, but somehow when i deploy my apps to android 4.1.2 action overflow is missing because it goes to traditional navigation hardware key ( check http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html ). But when i clicked it, it show this error :

```
01-25 17:16:08.582    8484-8484/bravostudio.icard E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:987)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1686)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2097)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3618)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3588)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2834)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me :) sorry for bad english.

Comment: Are you using appcompat-v7 version 21? I have experienced the same error and trying to find this error I did find this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78154